# How to validate field on last box focus out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am creating a form that has a account number field. This account number has 5 textboxes each having **size='1'**.

```
<div class="accountNumberWrapper">
    <input class="oneDigit" name="oneDigit" size="1" />
    <input class="twoDigit" name="twoDigit" size="1" />
    <input class="threeDigit" name="threeDigit" size="1" />
    <input class="fourDigit" name="fourDigit" size="1" />
    <input class="fiveDigit" name="fiveDigit" size="1" />
</div>
```

I am using **[jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)**, and want to validate the account number on **focusout of fifth box only**. I was using below code, but it is validating on tab out of every box,

```
rules: {
    'oneDigit': "meterReading", // custom method
    'twoDigit': "meterReading",
    'threeDigit': "meterReading",
    'fourDigit': "meterReading",
    'fiveDigit': "meterReading"
},      
groups:{
    'meter_reading': "oneDigit twoDigit threeDigit fourDigit fiveDigit"
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: I updated my answer, see below if it is what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery event handler:

```
$( "#target" ).focus(function() {
  /** Your code here **/
});
```

More about focus event handler:
https://api.jquery.com/focus/

```
$( "#target" ).focusout(function() {
  /** Your code here **/
});
```

More about focusout event handler:
https://api.jquery.com/focusout/

And use `.valid()` method for jQuery Validation Plugin
https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/

Comment: Not jQuery way, I am looking for a solution using jQuery Validator plugin!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery event [focusOut](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) with validation method [.valid()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid).

In your case it would be:

```
$(".fiveDigit").on('focusout', function() {
        $(".accountNumberWrapper input").valid();
    }
);
```

Comment: Not only  $(".fiveDigit").valid(); Need to validate all the 5 digits - entire account number, on focusout of fifth box.

Comment: @SouvikBanerjee I didn't understood what you wanted, I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

> I want to validate the account number on `focusout` of fifth box only

Write a custom `focusout` handler that triggers a validation test of the whole form on the `focusout` event of the fifth box.

```
$('[name="fiveDigit"]').on('focusout', function() {
    $('#myform').valid();  // trigger validation of form
});
```

> but it is validating on tab out of every box

Also disable the default `onfocusout` option of the plugin so that validation is not triggered when you move between the fields.

```
onfocusout: false
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/6mqtqeos/](http://jsfiddle.net/6mqtqeos/)**